# Dart continue to next case in switch if conditions not met

Tags: dart

I have a swtich with statements:

```
enum Fruit { mango, apple }

if (currentFruit) {
   case Fruit.mango:
     if (someCondition) {
       // do something
     } else {
       // Continue to next case <--
     }
     break;
   case Fruit.apple:
     if (someCondition) {
       // do something
     } else {
       // Continue to next case <--
     }
     break;
}
```

How can I continue to next case without breaking the switch?

When I remove the `break` statements it is producing an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create labels for each statement and point to which one you want to continue:

```dart
switch (currentFruit) {
mango: //This is a label
   case Fruit.mango:
     if (someCondition) {
       // do something
     } else {
       continue apple; // Switch to the "apple" case
     }
     break;
apple: //This is a label
   case Fruit.apple:
     if (someCondition) {
       // do something
     } else {
       continue mango;  // Switch to the "mango" case
     }
     break;
}
```